# Calculating Mean of 2nd Column Values for Each Text File

Tags: python, statistics

I have 10 text files and each of them has multiple rows and 3 columns delimited by a comma (`','`). My goal is to calculate mean between 10 text files for each row and by using only 2nd column values.

For e.g:

- `1.txt`: `[1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9; ...]`
- `2.txt`: `[10,11,12; 13,14,15; 16,17,18; ...]`
- `3.txt`: `[19,20,21; 22,23,24; 25,26,27; ...]`

I want the mean of the 2nd column values which are let's say:
A=(2+11+20)/3...then B=(5+14+23)/3...then C=(8+17+26)/3

therefore I will get `[A;B;C]` => 3x1 matrix

For now I only able to read all the files but not able to properly set them in the array I wanted.

```
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Chl_96", "*.txt"))

corpus = []

for file_path in file_list:
    with open(file_path) as f_input:
         corpus.append(f_input.read())
print (corpus)
```

Comment: Use the split command on your file contents.  Split on a semicolon to get rows.  Split rows by a comma to get individual elements.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the actual format of the data in the text files—it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't clearly described the format of the input data (in my opinion), here's something that will due it assuming it's something like this per file:

e.g. `2.txt`:

```
10,11,12
13,14,15
16,17,18
```

Code to compute the means of the second column of each of the rows in each of the input files. There's only three sample file, so that's how many means are calculated.

```
from ast import literal_eval
import glob
import os

COL = 1  # Column (second) with value to be averaged.
means = []  # One for column specified above in each file.

file_list = glob.iglob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Chl_96", "*.txt"))

for file_path in file_list:
    with open(file_path) as f_input:
        col_total = 0
        for i, line in enumerate(f_input):
            row = [col for col in line.rstrip().split(',')]
            col_total += int(row[COL])
        means.append(col_total / (i+1))

# Print calculated mean of second column of rows in each file.
print(means)  # -> [5.0, 14.0, 23.0]
```